# Get function parameters from a JS function which is a string

Tags: javascript, function, parsing, parameters

I am parsing a webpage and I obtain the following JS function as a string

```
"translate(737.4170532226562,136.14541625976562)"
```

I want to parse the string to obtain the two parameters of the function.

I can parse the string upto the '(' and ',' and ')' to get the arguments - I wanted to know if there is any other method to get the parameters from this string function.

Comment: this is called a production in a grammar, so hopefully this is what it will look like every time you parse.

Comment: Use a regex like `/translate\(([0-9\.]+),([0-9\.])\)/`. Or you could make a `translate(a,b)` function and `eval` the string, if you trust the source, of course.

Comment: hey @Dinesh take a look at my answer and let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex for this purpose. For example this one: `/([\d\.]+),([\d\.]+)/`

```js
var str = "translate(737.4170532226562,136.14541625976562)";
var args = /([\d\.]+),([\d\.]+)/.exec(str)
var a1 = args[1], a2 = args[2];

document.write(['First argument: ', a1, '<br> Second argument: ', a2].join(''))
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be overkill. But I was bored. So here is a function name parser. It gets the function name and the arguments.

```
var program = "translate(737.4170532226562,136.14541625976562)";

function Parser(s)
{
  this.text = s;
  this.length = s.length;
  this.position = 0;
  this.look = '0'
  this.next();
}
Parser.prototype.isName = function() {
    return this.look <= 'z' && this.look >= 'a' || this.look <= '9' && this.look >= '0' || this.look == '.'    
}
Parser.prototype.next = function() {
    this.look = this.text[this.position++];
}
Parser.prototype.getName = function() {
  var name = "";
  while(parser.isName()) {
    name += parser.look;
    parser.next();
  }
  return name;
}

var parser = new Parser(program);
var fname = parser.getName();
var args = [];

if(parser.look == '(') {
  parser.next();
    args.push(parser.getName());
    while(parser.look == ',') {
        parser.next();
        args.push(parser.getName());
    }
} else {
    throw new Error("name must be followed by ()")
}

console.log(fname, args);
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. I was wondering if we can have a smaller and more compact solution.

Comment: take a look at the angular source code and look at their regex for extracting variable names, but beggars shouldn't be choosers :)